# Displaying an image using XML and XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

My XML is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>    
<chapter id="ch01">
    <sect1>
        <title>Wattage</title>
        <para>Paragraph1</para>
        <para>Paragraph2</para>
        <para><figure>
                <caption>
                    <para>
                    <i>Sample image caption</i></para>
                </caption>
                <img src="myimagepath\cover_front.jpg"/>
            </figure>
        </para>
    </sect1>
</chapter>
```

I am having issues in displaying image on the HTML page where I am rendering my XML using XSLT (through C# aspx page).

My XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html> 
            <body>
                <h2>My Book</h2>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter/sect1" />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="chapter/sect1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="para/figure" />
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="title">
        <b><span style="font-size=22px;">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </span>
        </b>
        <br />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="para/figure">
        <xsl:element name="img">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Image is not displaying using above XSLT. Can anyone please help. I am new to XSLT.

Comment: Are you doing the transform server side or client side? Are the image paths relative to the URL that the client sees, or the XSLT file?

Comment: Are you sure your XML is structured well? Are you purposely doing this:  <para>Paragraph1<para>?

Comment: As @Rob suggested, I completed your input XML by adding two closing tags `</para>`. Be aware of that if checking your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The point where you're rendering para/figure isn't doing quite what you think, the point at which you select "." for the image source should in fact render all of:

```
<caption><para><i>Sample image caption</i></para></caption>
<img src="myimagepath\cover_front.jpg"/>
```

Try changing this template:  to:

```
<xsl:template match="para/figure">
    <img src="{img/@src}" />
</xsl:template>
```

(that's working from memory) so:

- para/figure has two child elements caption and img
- So we want to output a tag "img" (that the name is the same is incidental) with an attribute "src" (again incidental) and we want the src to be the src attribute (@ == attribute) of the img element of the current node. The curly braces enable magic to put the value in inline in the  tag you're rendering out.

Comment: Thank you so much, Murph.  <img src="{img/@src}" /> is displaying image now in my aspx page.

Comment: For the Rowland question, I am doing server side XSLT transformation through XML .Net control. My image path are relative to the URL. My question is what will be the code when my image path is relative to XSLT file? Can you please explain the concept. Thanks you so much.

Comment: There are multiple para tags in my XML for a single parent tag.